# How to get the value of the last record in each group?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table like this:

Table "**wallet*"

| amount | balance | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1000 | 2023-01-25 21:41:39 |
| -1000 | 0 | 2023-01-25 21:41:40 |
| 200000 | 200000 | 2023-01-25 22:30:10 |
| 10000 | 210000 | 2023-01-26 08:12:05 |
| 5000 | 215000 | 2023-01-26 09:10:12 |

And here is **the expected result**: (one row per day)

| min_balance | last_balance | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 200000 | 2023-01-25 |
| 210000 | 215000 | 2023-01-26 |

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT MIN(balance) min_balance,
       DATE(timestamp) date
FROM wallet
GROUP BY date
```

How can I add `last_balance`? Sadly there is no something like `LAST(balance)` in MySQL. By "last" I mean bigger `timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `MIN()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       MIN(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp)) AS min_balance, 
       FIRST_VALUE(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS last_balance,
       DATE(timestamp) AS date
FROM wallet;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fRuQHAg3).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8 or later, then we can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp) ORDER BY balance) rn_min,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn_last
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    DATE(timestamp) AS date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_min = 1 THEN balance END) AS min_balance,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_last = 1 THEN balance END) AS last_balance
FROM cte
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```